# Have past UNGA investigations without the cooperation of the host/target country achieved anything?

Tags: united-nations, unga, investigation

VOA/AP [wrote](https://www.voanews.com/a/un-to-establish-independent-body-to-clarify-fate-of-missing-syrians-/7161386.html) back in June:

> The U.N. General Assembly approved a resolution Thursday [Jun 29] that will establish an independent body to determine what happened to more than 130,000 people missing because of the conflict in Syria.
>
> The resolution, an important response to appeals by their families and loved ones, was adopted by the 193-member world body on a vote of 83-11 with 62 abstentions. Among those opposing the resolution was Syria, which said it will not cooperate with the new institution. Russia, China, North Korea, Venezuela, Cuba and Iran also voted no.
>
> [...] It authorizes the establishment of an Independent Institution of Missing Persons in the Syrian Arab Republic, under U.N. auspices, "to clarify the fate and whereabouts of all missing persons … and to provide adequate support to victims, survivors and the families of those missing."

Did the UNGA establish such inquiry commission before, over the objections of the host/target country? If so, did they ultimately achieve anything in terms of actual investigations?

Answer (score 2):

Achieving as in managed to write reports? Then the [Special Committee on Israeli Practices](https://www.ohchr.org/en/countries/palestine/special-committee-reports) would count if we consider Israel as the defacto country that controls access to the mission's region. The committee has its mandate from a UNGA resolution and the reports noted the lack of cooperation from Israel with the refusal of access to the disputed territories. Pre-COVID 2018 and 2019 missions were taken in neighboring Jordan, while post-COVID they conducted online meetings with UN agencies in the region and Palestinian ministries.

If you want a country that defacto and legally controls access to the region, there is [Human Rights inquiry on North Korea](https://www.ohchr.org/en/hr-bodies/hrc/co-idprk/reportofthe-commissionof-inquiry-dprk), though they're mandated by UNHCR instead of UNGA. With the lack of access to North Korea, and non-cooperation from any organization in North Korea proper, the committee obtains first-hand testimonies through public inquiries in Seoul, Tokyo, London, and Washington DC.